# cUrl passagem e recepção de parâmetros?

Tags: php, libcurl

Tenho o **link** $pagina abaixo:

```
$pagina = 'http://www.google.com.br';
```

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre:

```
$ch = curl_init($$pagina);
```

e:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $pagina );
```

Qual a diferença?

É que eu preciso *enviar* umas **informações** para a **API** da *CIELO* e depois de serem *processadas* essas **informações**, *receber* dele mesmo a **resposta**.

Também preciso enviar uma **variável** pelo **header** dessa **requisição**.

Gostaria de um exemplo fazendo favor!

Estou fazendo como abaixo, mas só dá erro de não recebimento da variável:

```
{"message":"Erro: token x-picpay-token obrigatório.","code":"401"}
```

O pessoal da **PicPay** disse que é obrigatório o envio de **x-picpay-token** no **header** da requisição mas acho que não estou fazendo correto

**Código**:

```
<?php

require_once "_global/_erros/erros.ini";

$site     = "http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br";

$producao = "https://appws.picpay.com/ecommerce/public/payments";

$headers  = array ( 
      "Content-Type   : application/json",
      "x-picpay-token : a840f8a9-e9b1-4dd5-a1c4-6ed32209d505"
);

$dados = array ( 
           "referenceId    : " . 1234,
           "callbackUrl    : " . $site . "/picpay.php",
           "returnUrl      : " . $site . "/picpayReturn.php",
           "value          : " . 222.22,
           "buyer          : " . array (
                "firstName : " . "Carlos",
                "lastName  : " . "Alberto",
                "document  : " . 12345678900,
                "email     : carcleo@gmail.com",
                "phone     : +55 32 3721-6149" //  +55 27 12345-6789
           ),
);

$ch = curl_init($producao);

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $producao );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST,  true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  json_encode ( $dados ) );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true );

$result = curl_exec( $ch );
$erro   = curl_error( $ch );
$info   = curl_getinfo( $ch );

print "<pre>";
    print_r( $result );
    print_r( $erro );
    //print_r( $info );
print "</pre>";

// Fecho a conexão
curl_close( $ch );

?>
```

Depois da orientação do colega e depois de alterar, agora tenho 2 problemas:

```
<?php

$site     = "http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br";

$producao = "https://appws.picpay.com/ecommerce/public/payments";

$headers  = array ( 
      "Content-Type   : application/json",
      "x-picpay-token : a840f8a9-e9b1-4dd5-a1c4-6ed32209d505"
);

$dados = array ( 
           "referenceId    : " . 1234,
           "callbackUrl    : " . $site . "/picpay.php",
           "returnUrl      : " . $site . "/picpayReturn.php",
           "value          : " . 222.22,
           "buyer          : " . array (
                "firstName : " . "Carlos",
                "lastName  : " . "Alberto",
                "document  : " . 12345678900,
                "email     : carcleo@gmail.com",
                "phone     : +55 32 3721-6149" //  +55 27 12345-6789
           ),
);

$ch = curl_init($producao);

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $producao );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST,  true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  json_encode ( $dados ) );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true );

$result = curl_exec( $ch );
$erro   = curl_error( $ch );
$info   = curl_getinfo( $ch );

print "<pre>";
    print_r( $result );
    print_r( $erro );
    //print_r( $info );
print "</pre>";

// Fecho a conexão
curl_close( $ch );

?>
```

Nessa linha,

```
 "phone     : +55 32 3721-6149" //  +55 27 12345-6789
```

Está dizendo:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs\hotplateprensas.com.br\picpay2.php on line 34
```

e continua dizendo:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Mon, 18 Feb 2019 23:12:11 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.8

    {"message":"Erro: x-picpay-token=': a840f8a9-e9b1-4dd5-a1c4-6ed32209d505' inválido.","code":"401"}
```

Comment: Ao invés de utilizar um array associativo, tente fazer `$headers = array (  "Content-Type: application/json",
      "x-picpay-token: a840f8a9-a8d9-4dd5-a1c3-6ed32209d505"
)`

Comment: ué. Mas é assim que está na pergunta. Não?

Comment: Não, você está usando um array associativo, e não um array de diversas strings, como diz a documentação. http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: entendi. Mas, por favor, após fazer as alterações urgiram outros problemas que adicionei ao final da pergunta

Comment: Aparentemente o token do picpay está incorreto, visto que o sistema da Cielo não conseguiu validá-lo. Sobre o erro na linha 34, a questão é que você está tentando concatenar uma array com uma string, coisa que não é possível. O que você pode fazer nesse caso é imprimir esse array como um json, usando a função `json_encode`

Comment: nuss, você é rápido, estava eu aqui arrumando o lance do array que havia percebo e reenviando a forma correta e você já conseguiu matar a charada. Mas seguinte, continua reclamando de não estar chegando o token lá na PicPay. Não é na CIELO. Esse não é o coreto. Mas já testei com o coreto é dá o mesmo erro, O pessoal da PicPay disse que precisava enviar o token no header da requisição. Ach que é isso que estou fazendo de errado.

Comment: Estranho... Parece ser um problema com a picpay... Testei o exemplo que tem na doc do site deles e mesmo o usuário de teste da API deu erro. A sua requisição está certa, ele está passando o header certinho. Eu sinceramente não sei o que possa ser o problema, talvez seja o caso de aguardar outro colegar ou contactar o suporte da PicPay para ver qual pode ser o problema.

Comment: hum, aqui, fiz outro teste aqui e deu erro de array de novo. Coloquei direto dessa vez sem variável, ,
       "phone     : +55 32 3721-6149" //  +55 27 12345-6789
     ),
);

Comment: http://hotplateprensas.com.br/picpay.php

Comment: Bom, o lance do erro do  array achei agora falta apenas o erro da autenticaçao